# how to get data from conn.query in dart

Tags: postgresql, dart, dart-async

I am doing dart with postgresql , I can't return data the conn.query(rows). but the results are coming ,how to return it, simple code is

```
    main(){
     someOtherFunc();
    }
   Future add() async{
   var uri = 'postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/testdb';
   var conn = await connect(uri);
   var sql = 'select * from test';
   return conn.query(sql).toList();
 }


 Future someOtherFunc() async {
   print(await add());
 }
```

I got return as  "Instance of '_Future'!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `await` in the function you call `add()` from, you get the desired result

```
Future add() async {
  var uri = 'postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/testdb';
  var conn = await connect(uri);
  var sql = 'select * from test';
  return conn.query(sql).toList();
}

Future someOtherFunc() async {
  print(await add());
}
```

`async` is contagious. When you call an async function, you can't return to sync execution. Everything that depends on the async results, needs to use `await` (or the "old" `.then((value) {})`) . `async` + `await` just create the illusion of sync execution.

Comment: var conn = await connect(uri); needs async....If we fixed it it returned the same.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't look close enough at the code. I updated my answer.

Comment: return the same result Instance of '_Future'!

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand your last comment. `await add()` unwraps the value from the `Future` before it is passed to `print(...)`.

Comment: no it prints the same not unwrapped it.....prints Instance of '_Future'!. so sad.

Comment: I don't have postgres set up to try it myself. I have no idea why this shouldn't work in your case. Can you please update your question with your current code?

Comment: This should be an equivalent example of your code https://dartpad.dartlang.org/edf62414cc4effd2c895. Please check what the return type of `conn.query(sql)` is. I assumed it's a stream.